# Calling Express get commands concurrently

Tags: node.js, events, express, concurrency, parallel-processing

so currently I have this function

```
app.get('/requestItems', function(req, res){
//Check if Bots are online
if(botQueue.length == 0){
  //If there are no bots in the queue to take the order, then we can't process it.
  console.log("Sorry no bots available");
  res.send("No Bots available ATM");
  return;
} else {
  var currentBot = botQueue.shift();
}
requestItems(currentBot.offerInstance, steamIDtoTrade, itemID, userAccessToken);

eventEmitter.on('requestOfferExpired', function(){
  console.log("Request offer has timed out/been cancelled");
  res.send("Request offer has timed out/been cancelled");
  botQueue.push(currentBot);
});
eventEmitter.on('requestOfferAccepted', function(){
  console.log("Request offer has completed");
  res.send("Request offer has completed");
  botQueue.push(currentBot);
});

});
```

When I call it, It takes about 5 minutes to run. While its running, I can't seem to make requests to the URL. I know node is a single threaded, but is there a way to run it parrallelly/concurrently? Or do I simply need to switch up my design strategy?

EDIT: requestItems function : http://pastebin.com/Eif5CeEv

Comment: FYI, it looks like you're adding new eventEmitter event handlers on every new `/requestItems` request.  I think that means you're getting a pile up of multiple event handlers on the same eventEmitter.

Comment: @jfriend00 How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: I don't follow what you're trying to do with your code well enough, but likely you need a new eventEmitter for each active request, not one global and then you need to make sure you never dup any event handlers on it.

Comment: But how would I go about sending a response if I move the eventEmitter into a global state? For example if I remove the emitter here, then I wouldn't have the scope of response. http://i.imgur.com/2yVSkuj.png

Comment: you pass your response variable to whatever code wants to create and send the response.

Answer (score 0):

If the 5 minutes per request is 100% CPU of node.js running with no IO, then you will not get any other requests processed during that time and you will need to run multiple node processes (probably in a cluster) in order to process multiple requests during that time.

If, on the other hand, much of that 5 minutes is doing IO (disk, database or socket), then a proper async IO design will allow your node server to process many requests during that time.

Since it seems unlikely that you're number crunching the CPU for 5 minutes in a row with no IO, my guess is that you need to switch to a proper async IO design and then you can use the advantages of node.js and can have many different requests processing at the same time.

---

You will need to disclose a lot more about what is going on in that 5 minutes for us to help more specifically.  Some questions about those 5 minutes:

1. What types of operations are taking the 5 minutes of time?
2. Are you using node.js async disk IO and async database IO in a way that allows other node.js events to flow while a given request is waiting for IO?
3. Is your request handling strategy designed to have multiple requests being processed at the same time?
4. Can you show us pieces of the code that are taking 5 minutes?

Comment: Ohh actually the main part takes < 5s, I just poll some information for five minutes during that time.

Comment: @Jake - if  you poll with timers, not with a loop and have a proper design, then you can handle zillions of requests during that time.  Or, even better, fix the design so you're not polling.  Show us the code.

Comment: I've added it to the OP, should be able to see where I've used timers.

Comment: @Jake - What do all the `steamOfferObj` methods do?  Are they all async and quick?  Do you only have one global named `eventEmitter`?  And, what is it?  If so, how could you possibly run multiple requests at the same time?  How big is `botQueue`?

Comment: steamOfferObj is the variable name for the node-steamoffer library.
Yes they are all async and quick. I do only have one eventEmitter, is that a problem?
Bot queue is about 3000+ bots. Sorry, relatively new to node!

Comment: @Jake - yeah, you can't be processing multiple requests at once if they're all sharing the same state.  They would each need their own independent state.

Comment: So how would I go about getting around that? Do I simply create a new state for every active call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72733/discussion-between-jake-and-jfriend00).

Comment: @Jake - the simplest way is you create new state for each request for the duration of the request when the request starts and you keep that state within a function call rather than in any shared global space.

Comment: @Jake - yeah, that's the idea.  I don't follow the specifics of what your code is doing to know if that's enough, but that's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Alright great. Would you follow it enough to be able to tell me about getting the 'zillion requests' you were talking about earlier?

Comment: @Jake - FYI, you can't return a result from an async function like `requestItems()`.  It returns immediately and the async stuff in it continues on for awhile.  If everything is async, you never use loops waiting for stuff and you have no shared global state, you should be able to have many requests processing at the same time.

Comment: Yea I'm figuring that out :P. Is there a good way to pass back returns from async functions? Also my issue seems to be HTTP blocking on express, and not really the concurrency stuff.

Comment: @Jake - You use callback functions or promises (which are really just enhanced callback functions) to return results from an async function.  I don't know what you mean about HTTP blocking on express.  It doesn't block and will handle many simultaneous requests if you code appropriately with only async-minded code.  You might have to increase a socket limit in node.js too.

Comment: Well lets say I make a request to requestItems. It sends a trade offer and polls that for 5 minutes. During the time that it is polling, I cannot send another requestItems call. That's what I mean by HTTP blocking.

Comment: @Jake - sure you can - why not?  The only reason you wouldn't be able to is limitations of your own code.  It's possible to write a crawler that has hundreds of open requests in process at the same time in node.js.  You are not dealing with a limitation of Express or node.js, only your own architecture.

Comment: Yea of course. How would I go about determining what is the bottleneck in my current code?